# Machine learning algorithm for mapping a 2d coordinate to a value

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I'm trying to build a program to map a 2d coordinate (latitude, longitude) to a float value. I have about 1 million rows of training data like

```
(41.140359, -8.612964) -> 65
... -> ...
```

I think this is a regression problem, except all of the regression examples I've found are only using 1 dimension, so I'm not sure.

What algorithm (or category of algorithms) should I use in this instance?

Comment: I think [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I think you first want to visualize a sub-sample of your data to see if there is any patterns by eye. My hunch is that nearest neighbors may work if target values have some patterns in terms of locations.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto I'm not sure how to use that, can you clarify? It seems it's used to project data into a lower dimension, is that right?

Comment: @ZichenWang That seems like a really good idea. I'll try to edit in a visualization.

Comment: @parchment PCA is used for reducing the number of dimensions, so that you can project your data on a 1-dimensional line. But that's not necessary as you can use regression models on n-dimensional data points.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to find a function, plot your data on an excel of python plot, you may see the kind of function you are looking for.

In addition, excel has a regression computation module.

Answer (score 0):

It is a regression problem and you can freely use e.g. [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) to solve it. The examples are often one-dimensional so it is easy to understand, however they work for an arbitrary number of dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use linear regression first.

Lets give an example using [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.rand(10, 2)
>>> x
array([[ 0.7920302 ,  0.05650698],
       [ 0.76380636,  0.07123805],
       [ 0.18650694,  0.89150851],
       [ 0.22730377,  0.83013102],
       [ 0.72369719,  0.07772721],
       [ 0.26277287,  0.44253368],
       [ 0.44421399,  0.98533921],
       [ 0.91476656,  0.27183732],
       [ 0.74745802,  0.08840694],
       [ 0.60000819,  0.67162258]])
>>> y = np.random.rand(10)
>>> y
array([ 0.53341968,  0.63964031,  0.46097061,  0.68602146,  0.20041928,
        0.42642768,  0.34039486,  0.93539655,  0.29946688,  0.57526445])
>>> m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(x, y)[0]
>>> print m,c
0.605269341974 0.370359070752
```

See documentation for more information about plotting and what those values represent.